# Is there any way to find out which stream triggers merge operator in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

Let's say there are two streams `a$` and `b$`. 
I *merge* `a$` and `b$` to get the value when either of them emits.

So the code would be like,

```
merge(a$, b$).subscribe((val) => // do something);
```

What I'm wondering is if there's any way to find out which stream triggers the operator other than setting some sort of a flag for each stream like below:

```
merge(
  a$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      fromA = true;
      fromB = false;
    })
  ),
  b$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      fromB = true;
      fromA = false;
     })
  )
).subscribe((val) => do something based on the flag);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `merge` operator doesn't give you this information directly, but you can still do without external state:

```
merge(
    a$.pipe(map(a => [a, 0])),
    b$.pipe(map(b => [b, 1]))
).subscribe(([value, index]) => { /*...*/ });
```

This idea can be easily transferred into a new operator on its own that does this for a list of passed observables automatically.

Comment: Brilliant! I appreciate it.